# Trying to get item id's for use with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

so I have a method that goes off whenever a button is clicked. the buttons are generated based on amount of rows in a table on a database. Each of them have a unique id which is set the same as the specific items id in the database (will make it easier for checkin in and out items.) So the method looks like this

```
function calculate(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
  var id = event.target.id;
  var valueofbut = event.target.value;
  if(valueofbut==="Check Out"){
    document.getElementById(id).value = "Check In";
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "checkitemin.php",
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Item has been successfully checked out" + msg );
  }); 

  }else{
    document.getElementById(id).value = "Check Out";
     $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "checkitemout.php",
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Item has been successfully checked in" + msg );
  }); 

  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to php and ajax, how can I pass the variable id into ajax for use in checkitemout.php.

My checkitemout.php looks like this

```
<?php//basically is there any way to use that variable id from the method in this document..?
 session_start();
 require_once 'Dbconnect.php';
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberid=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $usersemail = $userRow['email'];
 $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET name ='$usersemail' WHERE ";
 mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: I hope that php/sql stuff is just for learning. Looks dangerous ;)

Comment: @A.D. haha I havnt added security to this stuff yet. I know I should be using sqli, but I havnt learned the newer stuff yet :c all the other stuff in the web app is secured :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
function calculate(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
  var id = event.target.id;
  var valueofbut = event.target.value;
  if(valueofbut==="Check Out"){
    document.getElementById(id).value = "Check In";
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "checkitemin.php",
  data: {idparam:id}, //send value of variable id
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Item has been successfully checked out" + msg );
  }); 

  }else{
    document.getElementById(id).value = "Check Out";
     $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "checkitemout.php",
  data: {idparam:id},
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Item has been successfully checked in" + msg );
  }); 

  }
}
```

PHP

```
$id=$_POST['idparam']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I actually got it working through the use of cookies :)

Comment: is this method better ? because I'm actually not good with that

Comment: Yes it is, you see what if user has disabled cookies or is using private mode.

Comment: good point. I mean for what I'm personally doing it doenst matter. But I will change the code to what you put and let ya know if it works. That way I have a solid code for future reference